# Extended application descriptor file and invalid datasource

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I have two applications:

- **hrportalcore**: The core application with BaseController, ...
- **hrportalrequestleave**: A sample application extended from the hrportalcore application

The hrportalcore has the namespace **de.example.core** and there are the *dataSources* also maintained. (`sap.app.dataSources` in manifest.json). The datasource is:

```
[...]
"HRPOJavaLeave": {
   "uri": "<path>",
   "type": "OData",
   "settings": {
       "annotations": [],
       "odataVersion": "2.0",
       "localUri": ""
   }
}
[...]
```

The datasources can be used without any problems in the extended application but the console brings the following errors:

[image]

It says the datasource contains errors, but it can be used (strange?).

Another thing is, that the Component-preload.js file is loaded from a wrong place once a time. The application works without problems, but it is - as said - loaded once from a wrong location?

My manifest.json of the hrportalrequestleave looks like in the extension part (`sap.ui5.extends`):

```
[...]
"extends": {
    "component": "de.example.core",
    "extensions": {}
},
[...]
```

The parent is defined rightly in the *neo-app.json* as `/parent` to show to hrportalcore.

```
jQuery.sap.declare("de.example.request.leave.Component");

// use the load function for getting the optimized preload file if present
if (!jQuery.sap.isDeclared("de.example.core.Component")) {
    sap.ui.component.load({
        name: "de.example.core",
        // Use the below URL to run the extended application when SAP-delivered application is deployed on cloud
        url: jQuery.sap.getModulePath("de.example.request.leave") + "/parent"
            // we use a URL relative to our own component
            // extension application is deployed with customer namespace
    });
}

this.de.example.core.Component.extend("de.example.request.leave.Component", {
    metadata: {
        manifest: "json"
    }
});
```

**This all happens in the Fiori Launchpad of HANA Cloud Platform**

Comment: Just for clarification:
The app itself works without problems and displays your data correctly?
Your question is just referring to these error messages in the console log?

Comment: Yes, the app works, and yes the console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

**manifest.json of hrportalcore**: Always use the up-to-date version which you have deployed on your HCP in the `applicationVersion` property:

```
{
    "_version": "1.2.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "_version": "1.2.0",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.6.2"
        },
...
```

**manifest.json of hrportalrequestleave** (Extension project): As above, always use the up-to-date version which you have deployed on your HCP in the `applicationVersion` property.

### DataSource not found?!

If you have a extension project (like hrportalrequestleave < hrportalcore), then the *manifest.json* of both applications are merged like `jQuery.extend(...)`. All properties, expect the `sap.app` tree, because it describes really the application and can not be copied from parent extension.

Now, when you use a `dataSource` from the parent extension, it will not be found. That means for you, you must define the `sap.app.dataSources` in the extension project *manifest.json*.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the log

> "Error in application dependency de.example.core.Component: No descriptor was found"

suggests that the manifest.json contains a dependency to "de.example.core.Component" instead of "de.example.core". According to your code snippets, the "extends" dependency is correct. Do you have other dependencies?

The AppIndex in the backend calculates the transitive closure of dependencies and if it can't find an installation with that ID, the above error is created and logged on the client side.

If your manifest.json looks okay but might have contained a wrong dependency in the past, then it might be necessary to re-run the AppIndex (or schedule it for a regular run).

The fact that the app works despite the config error is caused by the code that you've shown above. It explicitly loads the de.example.core component from an explicitly calculated URL. But before that step, the framework already tries to load it, based on the information in the manifest.json and there the information about the explicit URL is missing.

BTW: the code that calculates the URL suggests that even after fixing the manifest.json, the AppIndex might not find the component as it seems to be stored in a sub package of the de.example.request.leave app. Not sure if the AppIndex can handle this (it can handle nested components if they are listed as embedded components in the top level manifest.json, but I'm not sure if it recognizes such embedded components in the dependencies section. As a result it might try to load the embedded component although it has been loaded together with the enclosing component already.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, I have no other dependencies. Do you have an example how an extension manifest.json must look like?